# why is "static" both storage class and linkage specifier?

Tags: c++, static

The static keyword defines how a variable is to be stored in memory, i.e., in the data segment if initialized or in the BSS if uninitialized. But the keyword also specifies how a variable is to be linked, i.e., local scope only.

How or why are these two things related? Can the two be separated, or was this a necessary design consideration?

IOW, why is it that if I want my variable to exist for the duration of the program, it must be linked internally?

Comment: No, the `static` keyword does not specify if the variable should be in the `data` or `bss` segment, it's only the initialization status that decides that (for systems that uses segments such as `data` and `bss`).

Comment: But isn't that the effect though? Initialized or uninitialized static variables are stored in Data Segment and BSS respectively, no? Even if it's an implementation detail and not necessarily mandated by the standard.

Comment: Local variable (automatic by default) are stored on stack and thus local to function.

Global variable are alive throughout the program life. (A variable that you exists for duration of program but with external linkage)

If you add static keyword with local variables, its scope remains unchanged but life is until the end of program.

If you add static keyword with global variable, life remains same but the linkage is internal.

Comment: @MohitJain yeah, I think that's my question... why is it that way? the keyword seems to be doing two very different things in the examples you mentioned. I'm curious as to why they didnt use two different keywords. I'm sure there's a good reason (well, one would hope anyway), I just don't see what it is.

Comment: Most of the answer to "why does static mean what it does in C++" is: "because C defined it that way." When it was originally defined in C, fitting the compiler into memory was enough of a challenge that minimizing key words bordered on a necessity.

Comment: @ash So are, for example, global *non-static* variables as well. A global non-static variable is stored in the data segment if it's initialized, and in the bss segment if it's not.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `static` can probably be seen as somewhat "overloaded".

The following usage-options are all viable:

- Static local variables
- Static global variables
- Static member variables
- Static global functions
- Static member functions

---

### Variables:

In terms of runtime, all types of static variables are essentially the same. They all reside in the **data-section** of the program, and their addresses remain constant throughout the execution of the program. So the only difference between them is during compilation, in the scope of declaration:

- Static local variable: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the function
- Static global variable: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the file
- Static member variable: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the class

---

### Functions:

In terms of runtime, all types of functions (static and non-static) are essentially the same. They all reside in the **code-section** of the program, and their addresses remain constant throughout the execution of the program. So the only difference between them is during compilation, in the scope of declaration:

- Static global function: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the file
- Static member function: recognized by the compiler only in the scope of the class

Comment: re "scope of the file", C++ doesn't have that. C has a notion of "file scope", which in C++ is namespace scope, just outside any function or class. But even the C notion doesn't refer to any particular file, and a translation unit is usually (in practice) composed of multiple files, brought together by the preprocessor. C++ does not even require the source code to be in files. Maybe replacing "file" with "translation unit" could rescue things.

Answer (score 1):

Re

> “why is it that if I want my variable to exist for the duration of the program, it must be linked internally?”

no that is not so.

Program-global variables are supported, and that's the default for a non-`const` namespace level variable. It's just wise to avoid them (to the extent possible).

---

Re apparent conflation of concepts in the single keyword `static`, since C++ doesn't support dynamic libraries, local to the translation unit linkage is not meaningful for lifetime shorter than the program execution.